# Submit Button Not Lining Up Correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I put my xml code inside a scrollview since I had more information on there than I did real estate, and my Submit button now rests on the editText2 above and I cant get it down.  The button is set to be below the edittext2 section but it clearly does not go there.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/sleeping_tracking"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/start_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/start_time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker1" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="@string/end_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/nap" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nights_sleep" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:text="@string/sleep"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="@string/end_time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/wakeups"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/comment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: 1 snap = 1000 words, so you should post problem snap also.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/103678987436785516340/albums/5614926899584644577/5688087579156325330?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

and it lowered, but I couldn't find out why it was displaying over the edittext

Answer (score 0):

[Mr. Intelwalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695156/intelwalk)
I tested xml layout code you posted, its working fine. The button was displayed below the edittext2 only. How you got above the edittxt2. if you interested please post the snapshot here.

In my output the button is in next line of edittext2, means completely in touch and below the edittext2. If we want gap we have to use top margin.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/103678987436785516340/albums/5614926899584644577/5688087579156325330?hl=en